# add a list to a list value python

Tags: python, list, variables, attributes

So I have this class called `Data`
And the class has two attributes; `var_names` and `units`
is it possible to append list elements of the list (which belongs to attribute `units`) to each element in the list called `var_names`? So when I make a new object called `myData`, the bellow output is possible (so the sublist `[1,2,3,4]` would be associated to `id` element?

```
>>> myData=Data([[1,2,3,4],["a","b","c","d"],
[2.3,2.1,2.5,3.1]],var_names=["id","name","length"])
>>> print myData
id name length
1    a    2.3
2    b    2.1
3    c    2.5
4    d    3.1
```

Or that's not possible? And be only achieved visually (way of formatting the output)

Comment: So, basically, it's a `namedtuple`?

Comment: I don't think I understand...

Comment: [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case. Because I got this object call and output, now I have to reproduce the code based by the given info:
var_names=["id","name","length"]
and this doesn't seem to be a namedtuple?

Answer (score 2):

You actually need namedtuple as others have suggested. Here is a possible implementation of what you would need

```
>>> class Data(object):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        args = args[0]
        var_names = kwargs['var_names']
        self.var_names = namedtuple('Data',var_names)
        self.units = [self.var_names(*e) for e in zip(*args)]
    def __repr__(self):
        fields = [e for e in vars(self.units[0])]
        fmt_string = '{:^10}'*len(fields)
        return '\n'.join(fmt_string.format(*units) for units in self.units)


>>> myData=Data([[1,2,3,4],["a","b","c","d"],
[2.3,2.1,2.5,3.1]],var_names=["id","name","length"])
>>> print myData
    1         a        2.3    
    2         b        2.1    
    3         c        2.5    
    4         d        3.1    
>>>
```

Comment: This sounds good... but what if I'd like to delete 'id' or 'name'
Because i've been playing a while with this solution. But I am unable to make a function which would delete values of a selected var

for example   my_Data.del('lenght')

so the out put would contain only id and name.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right I think using a dictionary in place of a list for `var_names` should do what you want.  Use `collections.OrderedDict` if ordering is important.

```
>>> import collections
>>> var_names = collections.OrderedDict([('id',[1,2,3,4]), 
                                         ('name',['a','b','c','d']), 
                                         ('length',[2.3,2.1,2.5,3.1])])
>>> for name, value in var_names.items(): 
...     print name + ': ' + str(value)
id: [1, 2, 3, 4]
name: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
length: [2.3, 2.1, 2.5, 3.1]
```